# Cryptography 0.0.6 not getting installed in Windows 10 UWP app

Tags: c#, windows, cryptography, uwp, aes

When I am trying to install Cryptography 0.0.6 in NuGet pakage for Windows 10 UWP app it gives me the below error:

```
Cryptography 0.0.6 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0.
Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0.
Cryptography 0.0.6 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm).
Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm).
Cryptography 0.0.6 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm-aot).
Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm-aot).
Cryptography 0.0.6 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64).
Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64).
Cryptography 0.0.6 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64-aot).
Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64-aot).
Cryptography 0.0.6 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86).
Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86).
Cryptography 0.0.6 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86-aot).
Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86-aot).
```

As I am new to Windows development and I want to use `RijndaelManaged` class for AES encryption so please provide me suggestions.

How can I install `Cryptography 0.0.6` or how to use `RijndaelManaged` class for AES encryption in Windows UWP?

Comment: [Simple AES Symmetric Key Encryption in WinRT](https://canbilgin.wordpress.com/2012/10/03/simple-aes-symmetric-key-encryption-in-winrt/) - this should work also for UWP applications. You don't need any NuGet packages

Comment: I wouldn't trust a library that mades a typo in its [package name](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cryptorgaphy/) :)